# How does the Scope affect the objects of the Bean?

Tags: java, jsf

I was reading this entire [introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope) to understand when and why we should choose a specific Scope, it is clear for static fields and methods, but for the objects of the Bean itself it is not, at least for me.

Bean1:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ConsultBean   implements java.io.Serializable {
    public  String name="oldName";
    
    public String getResults(){
    return "index";  
    }
    ..
```

Bean2:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean   implements java.io.Serializable {
    public  ConsultBean obj=new ConsultBean();
    
     public String show(){
     obj.setName("newName");
     return obj.getResults(); 
    }
    ..
```

index.jspx/xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid  columns="2">
<h:outputText value="Result:"/>
<h:outputText value="#{consultBean.name}"/> 
</h:panelGrid>
```

The result was: `oldName`!

But when:

```
public String getResults(){
    this.setName("New Name")
    return "index";  
    }
```

The result is STILL: `oldName`!!

Does the object where the call initiated matter?

Comment: I'm no JSF expert, but are you certain `show()` and `getResult()` are called?
Because these methods seem to be the only place where the name can be changed.
Also `show()` will never change anything as it's changing the name of `ConsultBean` created in `TestBean` itself. So it's a new object that isn't the same as the one used by JSF

Comment: Thank you @StijnVanBever, So JSF uses one object of the class an keep it, the rest are "Copies"! the scope is also meant only for that object?

Comment: If you do `new ConsultBean();` you don't create a managed bean saying this instace is not managed by JSF at all. On the other hand EL-Expressions like `#{consultBean.something}` do refer to the JSF managed bean. If you want `ConsultBean` to be injected to `TestBean.obj`, you'll have to annotate it with `@ManagedProperty`, so JSF would set `obj` to the JSF managed `ConsultBean` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `public  ConsultBean obj=new ConsultBean();`, you are not supposed to instantiate managed beans. It's the job of the framework to do it for you, that's the whole point of managed beans.

Inject `ConsultBean` with [ManagedProperty](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/).

Although, I would suggest you to use CDI instead of the old jsf bean api